# FileZilla - Tab overlay issue

Tags: unity, gtk, filezilla

Ubuntu Version: 14.10
FileZilla Version: 3.9.0.6

This is happening when I try to open a new tab. It overlays the current tabs.
Also the tabs are not switchable in this case.

```
(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
wxD-Bus: Signal from /org/freedesktop/DBus, member NameAcquired
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 2
wxD-Bus: Reply to RegisterClient, our object path is /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client10
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 3
wxD-Bus: Reply: Error: The name org.freedesktop.PowerManagement was not provided by any .service files
wxD-Bus: Falling back to org.gnome.SessionManager
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 4
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful, cookie is 176761874
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting idle
13:36:34: Debug: Failed to connect to session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 5
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

(prog-filezilla:13881): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion 'impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 6
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful, cookie is 1003446351
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting idle
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 7
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful
```

This is log when try to open FileZilla from console.

[image]

Comment: Is the FileZilla window maximized? Can't tell from the screenshot. If so, reduce the size and drag the FileZilla window to a slightly different position on the screen.

Comment: Hello @douggro I've tried to reduce and expand the size of window but the result is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Ubuntu

You can fix it by disabling the custom scrollbars:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

More information:
http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/9708

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a very similar issue with software on Ubuntu 15.10. (CodeBlocks gets affected in a similar way.) Because the scrollbars were changed in that version, Nin's answer made me wonder if that was the problem - it was.

I think the problem is that there is an interaction between wxWidgets (the GUI toolkit that Filezilla and Codeblocks are built on) and certain scrollbar configurations. Thus, this is actually a *much* deeper issue than just one version of Ubuntu or one application.

An alternative way to turn off the custom scrollbars is to install the `unity-tweak-tool`. Go to Scrolling, and set Scrollbars to Legacy.